# Grpc transfer big data, one unary call is slower than streaming,

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

I'm trying to transfer a big data between two services using grpc.

The data size is about 23M and is composed by 42 big List.

Then I test the performance using one unary call vs server side streaming(stream one list at a time).

The unary call takes 276.59 ms.

The streaming call takes 126.64 ms.

But if I change the data to contains 1000 small list, each list just have one number, the streaming call is much more slower than unary call.

Is the result normal? And Why?

Here is the server side code:

```
public override Task<MemDtoToWbs> GetLargeMEM(Empty request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    return Task.FromResult(MemData.GrpcLargeMem);
}
public override async Task StreamLargeMem(Empty request, IServerStreamWriter<LogDtoToWbs> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
{
    foreach (var log in MemData.GrpcLargeMem.Logs)
    {
         await responseStream.WriteAsync(log);
    }
}
```

I use the .net core 3.1 and grpc nuget package 2.32.0.
Run test in aks cluster.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, that's exactly why when talking about performance you may hear the phrase "everything is a trade-off". There's no one best approach, each situation requires doing things in certain ways.

Comment: Thanks @CamiloTerevinto for the reply. But I want to know what caused such a difference.

Comment: Basically, even though sending messages in streaming calls has very little overhead, when you send lots of small messages (such as in your case), the overhead for sending each message can add up and things can end up slower than if you sent everything in just one bunch (it of course depends how big that bunch is). Basically, streaming call is useful when your use case requires receiving data incrementally in portions (e.g you want to send data as soon as it becomes available), but it doesn't mean that splitting in many small messages is always faster (often it's not).

Answer (score 0):

I think @Jan Tattermusch is right.

I test in localhost, the TCP segment size is 64K.
When small messages is too small, like 32K, it only have 6.5K payload length in each TCP segment. But if message is big, it can use all the 64K.  So yes the overhead for sending each message can add up and things can end up slower.

So it's reasonable to me that streaming is faster if message is big.
Because sending data in server side and process data in client side is running in parallel.

[image]